# How to run pure pandas code in spark and see activity from spark webUI?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Does any one has idea how to run pandas program on spark standalone cluster machine(windows)? the program developed using pycharm  and pandas?

Here the issue is i am able to run from command prompt using spark-submit --master spark://sparkcas1:7077 project.py and  getting results. but the activity(status) I am not seeing @ workers and also Running Application status and Completed application status from spark web UI: :7077
in the pandas program I just included only one statement " from pyspark import SparkContext

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext
# reading csv file from url
workbook_loc = "c:\\2020\Book1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(workbook_loc, sheet_name='Sheet1')
# converting to dict
print(df)
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pandas code runs only on the driver and no workers are involved in this. So there is no point of using pandas code inside spark.

If you are using spark 3.0 you can run your pandas code distributed by converting the spark df as koalas

Comment: I did changes  getting issue ..any idea how to get of this..

import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyarrow
from databricks import koalas as ks
import time

workbook_loc = "c:\\2020\Book1.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(workbook_loc, sheet_name='Sheet1')
kdf = ks.from_pandas(df)
print(kdf)

from command i am executing above as spark-submit --master local  hello.py, gives following error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'databricks'


with pycharm working fine

Comment: It seems you have conflicting env

Comment: conflicting env?, any version issues do you think of?

Comment: I could able to run koalas code, after doing installation koalas from command prompt